# How do you calculate variance for percentages?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics

I know this seems like a simple questions but I am trying to wrap my head around calculating variance for percentages (e.g. 15%, 16%).

I know that 15% is equivalent to 0.15, but when I try to calculate the variance using “15” versus “0.15” format, my variance is in the order of 100x different. I wanna say this is due to the fact that the variance is squaring the difference between the mean and each sample, but what is the correct way of calculating variance for percentages?

For example let’s say my dataset is the following: 16.34%, 16.11%, 16.02%, 15.32%, 18.13%, 15.58%, 18.17%, 19.01%, 17.03%, 18.79%, 17.97%, 18.36%

I get about 1.58% if I use “16.34” as the format but 0.0158% if I use “0.1634”. Or do I need to do additions conversions?

Comment: you should use the actual number so that you don't have to worry about things being percentages. think of them as just numbers and take out the % by moving the decimal over. So 16 percent becomes 0.16.  you can always convert back later if you want.

Comment: Hi. So if I actually use the number then it comes out to be 0.0158%, which seems like too low of a variance. 

Since the percentage is derived from two separate values (one divided by the other), could I calculate the variance separately and then divide by one and the other? In order words, can I divide one variance by another?